# How to pass the right-hand side of a formula to another formula?

Tags: r

I would like to pass the right-hand side of a formula to an R function which then "adds" the left-hand side of the formula and calls `gam()`. I would like to achieve this without ugly as.formula() constructions etc.

I got stuck in the following minimal example, do you know what went wrong?

```
require(mgcv)
set.seed(0) ## set.seed(1)
gamEx1 <- gamSim(1, n=400, dist="normal", scale=2) ## simulate some data
str(gamEx1) ## display structure

## calling gam() and passing the right-hand side of a formula
gamFitter <- function(formula.RHS, data, ...){
    z <- 2*data$y + data$f0 # some given values
    gam(z ~ formula.RHS, data=data, ...) # call gam()
}

## call the function with the right-hand side of a formula
gamFitter(formula.RHS=~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3), data=gamEx1)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = z ~ formula.RHS, data = data,
                             drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
  invalid type (language) for variable 'formula.RHS'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that you should use the built in functionality of R, namely `update.formula`, no need to write a new function:

```
> form <- ~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)
> form
~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)
> update.formula(form, z ~ .)
z ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
```

Comment: Thanks, Derek, I did not know this function exists.

Comment: @MariusHofert It seems to me this answer is more elegant than the currently accepted. Could you reconsider the accept?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version building upon @gsk3's idea:

```
changeLHS <- function(formula, lhs) {
   if (length(formula) == 2) {
     formula[[3]] <- formula[[2]]
   }
   formula[[2]] <- substitute(lhs)
   formula
}

changeLHS(a~b+c, z+w)  # z + w ~ b + c
changeLHS(~b+c, z+w)   # z + w ~ b + c
```

So, your code becomes:

```
gamFitter <- function(formula.RHS, data, ...){
  frm <- changeLHS(formula.RHS, 2*y + f0)
  gam(frm, data=data, ...) # call gam()
}
```

Comment: *Nice*, thanks. I guess `rhs` should be `lhs` in `changeLHS` to make it more clear, but it definitely works well.

Comment: @MariusHofert - Good point, I changed it. Now the "right hand side" is left, right? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Kludgy but it works:

```
form1 <- as.formula("hi ~ lo + mid")
form2 <- as.formula("blue ~ red + green")
form2[[3]] <- form1[[3]]
> form2
blue ~ lo + mid
```

Comment: Well, as I wrote, I *don't* want to use `as.formula()` and strings, it's simply bad practice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MariusHofert - can you explain what is bad practice about `as.formula()`?

Comment: A formula is a formula -- and should be treated as such. Converting it to/treating it via strings is bad practice. Please note that the recommended approach to build functions with formulas is treated here: http://developer.r-project.org/model-fitting-functions.txt Two good examples which do *not* involve strings (and thus do not require `as.formula()`) are the functions `lm()` and `(mgcv::)gam`.

Comment: I only used as.formula in ehe examples.  The mechanism of manipulating the formulas does not rely on it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answers, if you need to replace LHS [programmatically by passing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967797/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-string-manipulation-to-programmatically-build) (à la `reformulate`), then two small tweaks can help.

Using @Tommy's approach:

```
changeLHS <- function(formula, lhs) {
    if (length(formula) == 2) {
        formula[[3]] <- formula[[2]]
    }
    formula[[2]] <- as.symbol(lhs)
    formula
}

form <- ~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)
changeLHS(form, "z")
## z ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
```

Using @Derek's approach:

```
update(form, reformulate(".", "z"))
## z ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)
```