# Looping Cox regression model over several predictor variables

Tags: r

I need to run cox regression model for several variables, so I want write a loop to realize it.
But it doesn't work anyway.
Below is my code used

```
names(Gen) 
varlist <- names(hsb2)[8:11]  ## get the variables i want to involve in loop
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
    coxph(substitute(Surv(Time, Status) ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = Gen, ties="efron")
})
```

I got the error information as

```
errors in terms.default(formula, special, data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute
```

Any one has the idea of how to solve this problem or how to write the codes?

Answer (score 5):

Because models evaluate their formulae in funny ways, you're better off creating a string and turning it into a formula <s>using `reformulate` as in 
[Is there a better alternative than string manipulation to programmatically build formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967797/in-r-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-string-manipulation-to-programmatically)</s> rather than `substitute`.  (`reformulate` is usually preferable, because it tests the input for syntactic correctness, but in this case it mangles the response variable.)

Create this temporary function:

```
tmpfun <- function(x) as.formula(paste("Surv(Time,Status)",x,sep="~"))
```

The body of the function provided to `lapply` could be:

```
coxph(tmpfun(x), data = Gen, ties="efron")
```

(you didn't provide a reproducible example, but I *think* this should work ...)

For extra (but totally unnecessary) coolness you might try instead replacing the entire `lapply` call with two separate `lapply` calls, one to make a list of formulae from the variable name list, and one to make a list of fitted models from the list of formulae.

```
formlist <- lapply(varlist,tmpfun)
models <- lapply(formlist,data=Gen,ties="efron")
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know (and can't guess, without more information) what your problem is with the code.  I admit I haven't tested it, but if you gave a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) I could test my answer for myself.  It would take me more time for me to make up a reproducible example, and it might not be what you wanted, so for now that burden is on you ...

Comment: (I did find one bug in my code by myself.  But you still need to give more information!)

Comment: OK, I tested for myself.  You (at least) need to use `tmpform <- as.formula(paste("Surv(Time,Status)",x,sep="~"))` rather than using `reformulate`.  When I get a chance I will come back and edit my answer to explain why.