# How to call lm with variables?

Tags: r, expression, lm

Given the following function:

```
f <- function (x, y, data) {
    linm <- lm(y ~ x, data)
    summary(linm)$r.squared
}
```

The following call fails:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4), d = c(5, 6))
f('a', 'b', d)
```

Since `lm` obviously searches for columns `x` and `y` rather than substituting the variable names with their contents). How can I rectify this?

I tried playing around with expressions and `substitute`, to no avail. Unfortunately I don’t understand entirely how R treats these objects and in which contexts expressions are evaluated so as a consequence I’m flying blindly. Here’s what I’ve tried (not working):

```
exp <- substitute(expression(y ~ x), list(x = x, y = y))
linm <- lm(formula = exp, data = data)
```

The `exp` object actually looks promising when inspecting; unfortunately I cannot convince `lm` to swallow it.

Comment: See `reformulate`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967797/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-string-manipulation-to-programmatically-build/12967834#12967834

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the `formula` function. The following should work :

```
f <- function (x, y, data) {
    linm <- lm(formula(paste(y,"~",x)), data)
    summary(linm)$r.squared
}
```

Comment: Very simple, very awesome. Very thanks.

Comment: also see `?reformulate`