# What is wrong with this syntax? Trying to create a function for performing multiple Cox regression on a stratification variable using purrr

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that runs a Cox regression on a data frame while stratifying on a given variable.

This is how the function looks now. Previously the function worked perfectly with covariates and follow_up_time as static variables inside the function body directly, but I want to make the function more general.

```
run_cox_reg <- function(dataframe, strata = NULL, follow_up_time, covariates) {
  
  result <- dataframe |> 
    group_by({{strata}}) |> 
    drop_na({{strata}}) |> 
    nest() |> 
    mutate(test_results = map(.x = data, 
                              .f = ~ coxph(Surv({{follow_up_time}}, death_all_cause) ~ covariates, data =.x) |> 
                                broom::tidy(conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE))
           
    ) |> 
    unnest(test_results) |> 
    select(strata, term, estimate, std.error, conf.low, conf.high) |> 
    ungroup()
  
  return(result)
  
}
```

When I try to run this line of code now, it does not work:

```
run_cox_reg(name_of_df, 
            strata = strata_variable,
            covariates = c("covariate1", "covariate2"),
            follow_up_time = follow_up_time_variable
)
```

The error says that the object that is follow_up_time is not found.

FYI, I have changed the names of the function inputs, but I have made sure that they are correct in the code I've run. So, the follow_up_time_variable do exist in the data frame I'm using, but it can't be accessed inside the function body.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The problem is that you need to be extra careful when inserting variables into formulas, especially in functions that are not from the "tidyverse" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384740/passing-data-variables-to-r-formulas for a start. It also seems odd to pass `covariates` as strings but the other columns as symbols.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are expecting `follow_up_time` and `covariates` to be magically substituted into the `coxph` formula. Formulas don't work that way. I would probably build the formula string ahead of time, then use `as.formula` on this string inside `coxph`.

There are a couple of other mis-steps in your code. For example, you need `{{` around `strata` in your `select` statement. You should also avoid hard-coding the `death_all_cause` column name so that you can re-use your function with other data sets.

For example, this rewritten version of your function can handle any survival data:

```r
run_cox_reg <- function(data, strata = NULL, time, status, covariates) {
  
  f <- paste0('Surv(', deparse(substitute(time)), ',',
                     deparse(substitute(status)), ') ~ ', 
                     paste(covariates, collapse = ' + '))
 
  data |> 
    group_by({{strata}}) |> 
    drop_na({{strata}}) |> 
    nest() |> 
    mutate(test_results = map(.x = data, 
      .f = ~ coxph(as.formula(f), data =.x) |> 
      broom::tidy(conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE))
    ) |>  
    unnest(test_results) |> 
    select({{strata}}, term, estimate, std.error, conf.low, conf.high) |> 
    ungroup()
}
```

Testing on the `lung` data frame that comes with the survival package, we get:

```r
run_cox_reg(lung, sex, time, status, c('ph.ecog', 'wt.loss'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>     sex term    estimate std.error conf.low conf.high
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 ph.ecog    1.58    0.149      1.18       2.11
#> 2     1 wt.loss    0.997   0.00758    0.982      1.01
#> 3     2 ph.ecog    2.07    0.237      1.30       3.29
#> 4     2 wt.loss    0.974   0.0133     0.949      1.00
```