# Why does this simple function calling `lm(..., subset)` fail?

Tags: r, function

I am working on a custom function that includes a call to `lm()`, but for some reason the function fails. I can't make any sense of why it fails.

Consider this example simplified to the bare-bones:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
    lm(form., data., subs., ...)
}
```

This will end up in an error:

```
myfun(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'subs.' not found
```

However using `lm()` directly will work just fine:

```
lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars, subset = TRUE)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          cyl           hp  
##    36.90833     -2.26469     -0.01912
```

I tried debugging, but still can't get to the bottom of the problem. Why does the custom function fail? Clearly `subs.` *has* been supplied to the function...

---

### Edit:

While most of the solutions suggested below help in this simple case, the function will still fail if I add a simple twist. For instance `expand.model.frame()` relies on the formula's environment, but fails if I use the normal evaluation solution:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
    fit <- lm(form., data.[ subs., ], ...)
    expand.model.frame(fit, ~ drat)
}

myfun(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'data.' not found
```

This is obviously related to the original issue, but I can't figure how. Is the environment of the model formula somehow corrupted?

Comment: A short answer is probably to not single out the `subset` argument. Just pass everything in a named fashion, via `...`.

Comment: @joran Yes, this could be done, but I'm dealing with a number of different functions in my custom fun, and passing it all through `...` may not be a roust solution. I may end up passing some arguments to the wrong function. I still don't understand why the function in the question would fail...

Comment: It's complicated, and I'm struggling this early in the morning (for me) to explain it clearly. Basically it boils down to the rather large amount of special evaluation taking place in `lm`.

Comment: @joran Who said anything about R not being quirky... So what is the kosher way around this "special evaluation"? Using `...` or doing `match.call()` and then match desired arguments followed by a `do.call()` (basically the work-flow done in `lm`)?

Comment: Another oddity - if you assign `subs. <- TRUE` globally first, then the function will work.

Comment: @joran Could you please check the edited question? Some of the proposed solutions don't seem to help if there is a subsequent e.g. `expand.data.frame()` call which relies on the environment of the model formula... Can't quite understand what is still going wrong...

Comment: Roland already answered this in the most global sense: stop using special evaluation. Pass the formula as a character and coerce to formula when you call `lm`. Note that this idea is already suggested in an existing answer.

Comment: @joran I may be wrong, but my understanding is that Roland's suggestion was to avoid using the `subset` argument altogether. The "pass character and coerce to formula" approach still relies on the special evaluation going on in `lm()` for the `subset` argument. And this latter approach will indeed work in the `expand.model.frame()` case, but again I'm not sure why... In any case, thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Roland's very first contribution was: "The clean solution is to use standard evaluation". The difference is only a matter of degree. I'm not sure how many different ways all these people can explain that formulas have attached environments, and that where the formula is created influences where things are looked for, and hence formulas created at the top level will be attached to the global environment. And the global environment doesn't know about the arguments to `myfun`.

Comment: @joran Thank you, I think I'm starting to get the hang of it. I've now edited my answer with what seems to me a more robust approach.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments, another solution would be to avoid the `subset` argument altogether in non-interactive use, and use standard evaluation instead:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
    lm(form., data.[ subs., ], ...)
}
```

Now this works as expected:

```
myfun(formula(mpg ~ cyl + hp), mtcars, TRUE)
```

---

However this won't still be enough if your custom function subsequently contains calls like `expand.model.frame()` or similar, which seem to be themselves sensitive to the non-standard evaluation of the `subset` argument. To make the function robust and avoid surprises, you need to both (1) define the formula within the custom function (see also the [`reformulate` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967797/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-string-manipulation-to-programmatically-build)) and (2) subset the data *prior* to the `lm()` call while conspicuously avoiding the `subset` argument.

Like this:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
    stopifnot(is.character(form.))
    data. <- data.[ subs., ]
    fit <- lm(as.formula(form.), data., ...)
    expand.model.frame(fit, ~ drat)
}

myfun("mpg ~ cyl + hp", mtcars, TRUE)
```

I tried using either (1) or (2), but still managed to run into strange errors from some functions, and it's only with both (1) and (2) that the errors seem to have gone away...

Answer (score 4):

The reason this function doesn't work is because of the way the argument `subset` is evaluated:

> All of ‘weights’, ‘subset’ and ‘offset’ are evaluated in the same
>   way as variables in ‘formula’, that is first in ‘data’ and then in
>   the environment of ‘formula’.

In other words, `lm` looks for a variable named `subs.` in `data` and then in the environment of `formula`, and since there is no `subs.` variable in either of those environments it produces an error.

Comment: What is the "correct" way to work around this special evaluation, besides using only `...` in the function definition?

Comment: There is no clean solution. The function `myfun` has to add `subs.` to `data` and/or to the environment of formula, but this will overwrite any variables with the same name already present in these environments.

Comment: @landroni See my new comment (and change of heart) on the other answer.

Comment: The clean solution is to use standard evaluation, i.e., avoid `lm`'s `subset` argument in non-interactive use.

Comment: @Roland Do you mean that I should avoid the `subset` argument altogether, and subset the `data.frame` directly using `mtcars[ subs., ]`?

Comment: @landroni Since you write the wrapper function anyway: yes.

Comment: @Roland This solution doesn't seem to help if there is a subsequent e.g. `expand.data.frame()` call which relies on the environment of the model formula... Could you please check the edited question?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
    lm(as.formula(form.), data., subs., ...)
}
```

Call it as `myfun("mpg ~ cyl + hp", mtcars, T)`. This forces the formula to be created in the environment of the function `myfun` which will then contain `subs.`.

Comment: @joran Maybe - maybe not. The proposed code does actually fix the problem that is popping up but I agree it isn't ideal.

Comment: I've changed my mind about this answer. Passing the formula as a character and then coercing it when calling `lm` forces the environment of the formula to be the enclosing env of the `lm` call, which will contain the arguments `form.`, `data.` and `subs.`, so it will be evaluated correctly. This seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: ...also note that all of this is actually taking place in `model.frame.default`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer of @ErnestA you can modify your function to ensure that `subs.` is present in the environment of formula `form.`:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
assign("subs.", subs., envir=environment(form.))
lm(form., data., subs., ...)
}
```

ETA to avoid contaminating the environment of `form` you can create a new environment thus:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
environment(form.) <- new.env(parent=environment(form.))
assign("subs.", subs., envir=environment(form.))
lm(form., data., subs., ...)
}
```

ETA perhaps the neatest way of fixing the lm issue alone is to set the environment of `form.` to that of `myfun`:

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
environment(form.) <- environment()
lm(form., data., subs., ...)
}
myfun(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## Call:
##   lm(formula = form., data = data., subset = subs.)
## 
## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)          cyl           hp  
##      36.90833     -2.26469     -0.01912
```

Turning to the `expand.model.frame` issue, `subs.` is not found although it's in the environment which `?expand.model.frame` says is used. Is this a bug in expand.model.frame? or at least a conflict with the documentation?

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
environment(form.) <- environment()
fit <- lm(form., data., subs., ...)
print(ls(environment(formula(fit))))
expand.model.frame(fit, ~drat )
}
myfun(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## [1] "data." "fit"   "form." "subs."
##  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'subs.' not found
```

Putting `subs.` into the parent environment seems to work.

```
myfun <- function(form., data., subs., ...){
environment(form.) <- environment()
fit <- lm(form., data., subs., ...)
assign("subs.", subs., envir = parent.env(environment(formula(fit))))
expand.model.frame(fit, ~drat)
}
myfun(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars, TRUE)
## mpg cyl  hp drat
## Mazda RX4           21.0   6 110 3.90
## Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 110 3.90
## Datsun 710          22.8   4  93 3.85
## Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 110 3.08
## etc.
```

But this has the issues of contaminating the parent environment, in this case `R_GlobalEnv`. I haven't been able to make it work using anything other than `R_GlobalEnv` as the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What could be contaminated in the first case?

Comment: In a comment on his answer @Ernest A correctly said "The function myfun has to add subs. to data and/or to the environment of formula, but this will overwrite any variables with the same name already present in these environments". By default the environment of `form.` is that in which it is created; `R_GlobalEnv` if your example call to `myfun` is from the command prompt. To avoid creating/overwriting `subs.` in that environment I make the environment of `form.` a new, empty environment in which I can create `subs.`. This doesn't seem to fix your `expand.model.frame` issue :-(