# Adding letter to a string vector in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

Disregarding the hashtaged lines in my `input`, is there a way to add:

- `A*` before "alphanumeric" elements that don't have a `*` prefix and appear after `~` and
- `R*` before "alphanumeric" elements that don't have a `*` prefix and appear after `~~`?

Desired `output` is shown below.

```
input <- "y ~ x1 + x2
           ## Variances of x1 and x2 are 1
           x1 ~~ 1*x1
           x2 ~~ 1*x2
           ## x1 and x2 are correlated
           x1 ~~ x2"

output <- "y ~ A*x1 + A*x2
           ## Variances of x1 and x2 are 1
           x1 ~~ 1*x1
           x2 ~~ 1*x2
           ## x1 and x2 are correlated
           x1 ~~ R*x2"
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why did you remove the [tag:regex] tag? It seems usable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_replace_all()` and make use of the match groups.
In the example below I am using three stages to achieve the result you
specify.

```r
library(stringr)

res <-
  str_replace_all(input,
                  " ~ ([a-z])",
                  " ~ A*\\1") |>
  str_replace_all("\\+ ([a-z])",
                  "+ A*\\1") |>
  str_replace_all("~~ ([a-z])",
                  "~~ R*\\1")

cat(res)
#> y ~ A*x1 + A*x2
#>          ## Variances of x1 and x2 are 1
#>          x1 ~~ 1*x1
#>          x2 ~~ 1*x2
#>          ## x1 and x2 are correlated
#>          x1 ~~ R*x2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Till. May I ask a question regarding a possibility? Is it possible to add succession to `A*` and `R*`. For example, the first mention of `A*` will be `A1*`, the second `A2*` etc. and the same with `R*`?

Comment: I don't think there is a quick way to do this using the regex from my answer. Since it looks like you are trying to build formulas programmatically, maybe you want to look into `reforumlate()` instead? Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967834/4821142) that showcases its use.

Comment: I checked out `reforumlate()`, I don't think it works in this case. But another possibility,  Is it possible to make `~` to both include `~` OR `=~`?

Answer (score 0):

Use "gsub" :

```
   # Input string
input <- "y ~ x1 + x2
           ## Variances of x1 and x2 are 1
           x1 ~~ 1*x1
           x2 ~~ 1*x2
           ## x1 and x2 are correlated
           x1 ~~ x2"

# Function to add prefixes before alphanumeric elements based on patterns
addPrefixes <- function(input) {
  # Add "A*" before alphanumeric elements that don't have a * prefix and appear after ~
  output <- gsub("(?<=~ )([^*\\s]+)", "A*\\1", input, perl = TRUE)
  
  # Add "R*" before alphanumeric elements that don't have a * prefix and appear after ~~
  output <- gsub("(?<=~~ )([^*\\s]+)", "R*\\1", output, perl = TRUE)
  
  return(output)
}

output <- addPrefixes(input)
cat(output)
```

Comment: `x1 ~~ R*A*1*x1`

Comment: Shima, thank you. Unfortunately, it seems your function doesn't produce the desired `output`, as r2evans mentioned.